# Accessing scope within directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a controller which is charge of getting event json data and if there is data, update the dom with data, else update dom with error message:

```
//Controller.js
myApp.controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope','API', function ($scope, api) {
    var events = api.getEvents(); //events: {data: [], error: {message: 'Some message'}}
}]);

//Directives.js
myApp.directive('notification', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: notificationLink
    };
});
/**
 * Creates notification with given message
 */
var notificationLink = function($scope, element, attrs) {
    $scope.$watch('notification', function(message) {
        element.children('#message').text(message);
        element.slideDown('slow');
        element.children('.close').bind('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            element.slideUp('slow', function () {
                element.children('#message').empty();
            });
       });
    });
};
//Services.js
...
$http.get(rest.getEventsUrl()).success(function (data) {
        // Do something with data
    }).error(function (data) {
        $window.notification = data;
    });
```

Issue is that the element changes are triggered but $window.notification has nothing in it.

Edit: Attempted to try with $watch.

Edit: After moving both sets of html to one controller, the DOM manipulation works with $watch(). Thanks to both you of you for your help!

Comment: empty isolated scope in directive is one issue...get rid of it, other is that AJAX is asynchronous so `if(events.data)` will always be false...use $http callbacks to set the data

Comment: So I took out the isolated scope in the directive, and the $http callback for error currently is just setting the return value to a variable.So do I need to be able to call the directive to trigger the dom changes?

Comment: `getEvents()` will return promise, assuming is using `$http`.....try wrap `if(events.data` in `.then()`. Show the `getEvents()` code

Comment: I edited the above to try it with a $watch. Is that the direction I want to head? I just want to trigger the dom manipluation when the error occurs in the $http call.

Comment: might work...except is watching for scope property   wouold need `$scope.notification =$window.notification` the way you have it

Comment: Well I found out that I can't pass $scope in the service unless I'm not setting it up right.

Comment: right... put the `notication=$window.notification` in scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the result of your http request to a scope variable in your controller. Then watch that variable in your directive.

```
myApp.controller('EventsCtrl', ['$scope', 'API',
    function ($scope, api) {
        $scope.events = api.getEvents(); //events: {data: [], error: {message: 'Some message'}}
    }
]);

//Directives.js
myApp.directive('notification', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: notificationLink
    };
});

var notificationLink = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch('events', function (newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue !== oldValue) {
            if (scope.events.data.length) {
                //Display Data
            } else {
                //Display Error
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: This would work except the scope for the notification should be global and the events should be only for the event controller.